# Why do some `img` tags have no end tag while others do?

Tags: html, web

I read in tutorials that `img` tags don't have ending tag. But, while inspecting html of various pages I noticed that some `img` tags have ending tag `</img>` or `<img ... />` and some don't have ending tag and appear just `<img ... >`. In what cases they don't have an ending tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- XHTML requires that *all* elements be explicitly ended (e.g. `</img>`) but provides alternative syntax with a `/` at the end of the start tag (instead of an end tag) for elements which have no content.
- HTML forbids end tags on `<img>` elements but (for backwards compatibility with XHTML) permits a meaningless `/` to appear at the end of a start tag on elements where the end tag is forbidden.
- People also make mistakes

Comment: Is there a reason to use both types on the same page? I saw a page with this html `<div><img ...><div><img... /></div></div>`.

Comment: @theateist — Humans are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `<img ... />` on a 'self-closing tag' is valid in HTML, but not required.

It was required in the stricter XHTML, a markup language similar to HTML, to signify that a tag was self-closing. XHTML has largely lost out in popularity to HTML due to the latter being more lenient and more widely supported.

Because a lot of developers learned and used XHTML, many still use the self closing tag syntax despite it not being required. `<img ...>` is the recommended usage.

As an interesting side note, this syntax is now used again in React/JSX components.

Answer (score -1):

In HTML, the img tag is what's known as a "void element". Void elements are elements that don't have any content or nested elements. As a result, they don't require a closing tag.

For example, the following `img` tag is perfectly valid:

```
<img src="example.jpg">
```

This is because there is no content or nested elements within the `img` tag, so it doesn't require a closing tag.

However, some img tags may include additional attributes, such as `alt`, `width`, and `height`. In these cases, the `img` tag still doesn't require a closing tag, but some people prefer to include it anyway for consistency and readability purposes. Here's an example of an `img` tag with additional attributes and a closing tag:

```
<img src="example.jpg" alt="Example Image" width="500" height="300">
```

Comment: "doesn't technically require" is an understatement. [HTML _forbids_ a closing tag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element).

Comment: Okay i agree, Got your point